# let aligned blocks float left in align*

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

I'm using `align*` to comment some equations:

```
\begin{align*}
&loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong \\
&short, &comment 1 \\
&not\; so\; short, &comment 2 \\
\end{align*}
```

It produces this output:

[image]

I would like to have the two comments float left, under the `looooong` part. Ideally, it should look somewhat like this (I hacked this output together by inserting lots of `\;` in front of the first comment):

[image]

How can I get this behaviour ?

Please note: I'm using text here, but that's just to produce a more readable example. Actually I'm using align for long and ugly equations. So the solution should work in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aligned` inside of `align*` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong  \\
&\begin{aligned}[t]
& short,            & comment 1 \\
& not\; so\; short, & comment 2 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You beat me by a minute...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility with `alignat*` and `\mathrlap` from `mathtools`. What should be  ‘rlapped’ has to be decided in each case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&l\mathrlap{oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong} \\
&short, &\qquad & \text{comment 1} \\
&not\; so\; short, & & \text{comment 2} \\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document} \stackrel{\uparrow\\k}
```

[image]